# C# CPU Scheduler

Tags: c#, console-application

I am attempting to make a basic CPU scheduler, however I am having some minor issues with creating the c# console app. I am trying to continually get user input and add a new process until the user enters an id of -1. The issue I am having is that I am unable to properly get and set the fields for each process from the user input.

Scheduler:

```
public class Scheduler
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Algorithm();
    }

    private const int FCFS = 1;
    private const int SRJF = 2;
    List<Process> Processes = new List<Process>();

    public Scheduler(int id, int burstLength, int arrivalTime)
    {
        var processes = new Process
        {
            Id = id,
            BurstLength = burstLength,
            ArrivalTime = arrivalTime
        };
    }

    public static void Algorithm()
    {
        bool addProcess = true;
        Process processes = new Process();

        while (addProcess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ENTER PROCESS ID (-1 to END): ");
            var input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            processes.Id = input;

            if (input == -1)
            {
                addProcess = false;
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ENTER PROCESS ARRIVAL TIME: ");
                processes.ArrivalTime = input;

                Console.WriteLine("ENTER PROCESS BURST TIME: ");
                processes.BurstLength = input;
                
                Console.WriteLine("SELECT ALGORITHM: 1 - FCFS, 2 - SRJF: ");
                Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine(processes);

                if (input == 1)
                {
                    //FCFS();
                }
                else
                {
                    //SRJF();
                }
            }              
        }
    }
}
```

Process:

```
public class Process
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public int BurstLength { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How is this a **CPU** scheduler though? Your code isn't running in kernel-mode, interrupting running processes or issuing time-quanta.... From what I can tell it's a **conceptual model** of an OS' scheduler.

Answer (score 3):

Disregarding any other problem, you are only reading form the Console once, you need to read from the console for every property

**Example**

```
Console.WriteLine("ENTER PROCESS ARRIVAL TIME: ");
processes.ArrivalTime = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

<sub>***Note**, don't trust the user to do the right thing. Use [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) instead, and handle the case they get it wrong*</sub>

Comment: As a side question, I just realized that I can't add a single process to the list of processes because I need to write them all to the console after inputs. How would I go about adding individual processes to a list of processes to display in the console?

Comment: @simplest `Processes.Add(process);` ? anyway my time has run out for the day and i need to go, if you have another question, feel free to ask a new one. Good luck